# How to get the particular value of column using the primary key - entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have different tables.
For example Table 1 contains the name of Persons
Table 2 contains the Country name and Person Id

```
Table 1:
PersonId     PersonName
1            John
2            Smith
3            Kelly


Table 2:
LocationId   Continent      Country     PersonId
1            Asia           Japan       1
2            Asia           China       2

// There is C# method where PersonId should be passed.. suppose id=2 is passed

var person = await _repository.Person.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PersonId == id); //This find Smith from DB
var location = await _repository.Location.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.LocationId == person.PersonId);   
// location variable will get all values of second row from Table 2 i.e LocationID=2, Continent=Asia, Country=China, PersonId=2
// but i just need value of Country column i.e China of PersonId=2

// Though I can get CountryName from this -- have to write below extra code for that
var country = location.Country;   // this will get Country = China

How can I achieve this in a single line?

// something like
var location = await _repository.Location.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.LocationId == person.PersonId).Country();
```

Comment: By giving your Person class a Country property and `Include()`ing that navigation property. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var country = await _repository.Location.Where(x => x.LocationId == person.PersonId).Select(l => l.Country).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at creating a [Navigation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) on the person object so EF can automatically map the relationship for you. You can then choose to either Lazy load, or eager load the country in one query with include.

Answer (score 0):

```
//First Method :

Entity await _repository = new Entity() // object of your entity.
var Result = (from a in await _repository.Person.Where(a=>a.PersonId == id)
              from b in await _repository.Location.Where(b=>b.PersonId=a.PersonId)
              select new 
              {
                 a.PersonId,a.PersonName,b.Country
              }).SingleOrDefault();
Result.Country; // Here you can get country,also get other values PersonName,PersonId

//Second Method :

Entity await _repository = new Entity() // object of your entity.
var Result = (from a in await _repository.Location.Where(a=>a.PersonId == id)select 
              a.Country).SingleOrDefault(); //other wise you can select 'a'.  
Result.Country; // Here you can get country
```